# VBA, Extract a specified string after file name

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I have a file in the above format. List of some file names(can be in both any col), then a few rows later will have the Expected time, then repeats for more files and another expected time,

I have the current code to copy/paste file names based on wildcard I specify to another sheet. (It extracts all files names based on '/' )

My question is, how can I extract the "STEP_EXPECTED_TIME" along with these files in my other sheet. So column A would be my file name, B would be my step expected time. I need to link these together.

The problem is I need the file name with the corresponding step expected time. There are many file grouping with 1 expected time.

Current code to find file names:

```
Sub ExtractFileNames()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim R As Range, c As Range, copyTo As Range
    Dim startCell As String

Set copyTo = Sheets(2).Range("A1")
Set R = Intersect(Sheets(1).UsedRange, Sheets(1).Range("A:D"))

Set c = R.Find("*/*")
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    startCell = c.Address
    Do
        copyTo.Value = c.Value
        Set copyTo = copyTo.Offset(1)
        Set c = R.FindNext(c)
    Loop Until c Is Nothing Or c.Address = startCell
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why don't you repeat the above code with the search string `STEP_EXPECTED_TIME` and then "attach / link" these expected times? If you start with your search in the top-left of the sheet and then do the search by row then you can extract and save the expected times next to any file name already extracted (with the other code before) where (1) the row number for the file name is smaller when compared to the row number for the expected time and (2) there is no expected time yet linked to that file name. Done.

Comment: @Ralph , Hi Ralph, good idea, the problem is knowing how to link the expected times to these. I'm having trouble putting it together in a code.

Comment: Unsure how to link the multiple files to the 1 expected time, then fill that down, then repeat the next grouping of files.